# android share intent only to google drive

Tags: android, android-intent, share

i've set share intent for sharing image and title, but it's only get directed to google drive, and i dont understand why.. here is the code:

```
Intent shareCaptionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareCaptionIntent.setType("image/*");

                //set photo
                Uri examplePhoto = Uri.fromFile(getExternalFilesDir(filepath[position]));
                shareCaptionIntent.setData(examplePhoto);
                shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, examplePhoto);

                //set caption
                shareCaptionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, modelname);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareCaptionIntent,"share using:"));
```

Comment: Maybe previously you have set the Google Drive as default app to open `image/*`.

Comment: Since you know the MIME type of the image, use a real MIME type rather than `image/*`, and see if that helps. Beyond that, what else on your device were you expecting to handle sharing of images?

Comment: i didnt set the google drive to be the default. if i write "image/jpeg" it doesnt help. i have facebook, tweeter, whatsup, thats where i want to share images